# Can react router and maps be used to create an add new page function?

Tags: mysql, react-router, onchange, map-function, react-router-component

I am fairly new to react but doing well! I am looking to build a simple 'add' profile application. My UX designs include the following flow:

1. Home page (with add new page button)
2. Opens a blank page (with a save button that returns to home page)
3. Home page is rendered, but with a card component that is a link to the page that was just created.

My application currently has react router but for basic links between home and other pages, but this I think might be different.

What would be the best methods for this to work? I know it might have something to do with mapping a reusable 'new page component' and 'card component', with the card component rendering with the correct routing, but would I need something else like MySQL?

Thank you

Comment: pick a react book, it'll explain most of your question. In short, you install a route called "/card/:id" and then navigate to it when the record is ready.

Comment: Thank for your help. One of the books I have is really useful but it doesn't cover react router, but it's almost got me thinking about the right areas to start - but what's confusing me is the whole map function / router, in that it as something to do with using the ID's of routes and mapping them